# Plot features cropped by Margin

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

When I compile the following MWE I observe that the maximum point (3,5) is significantly cut/cropped by the margins.

The following example is drastically reduced for simplicity.

In my actual data the following are all impacted by limiting my `coord_cartesian` manually if the coresponding x-axis aesthetic is on the max x value.

- Point symbol
- Error bars
- Statistical symbols inserted by text annotation

MWE

```
library(ggplot2)
library("grid")

print("Program started")

n = c(0.1,2, 3, 5) 
s = c(0,1, 2, 3)  
df = data.frame(n, s)

gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x=s, y=n))
gg <- gg + geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=NULL), size = 1.5) 
gg <- gg + geom_line(position=position_dodge(width=NULL))

gg <- gg + coord_cartesian( ylim = c(0, 5), xlim = c((-0.05)*3, 3));

print(gg)

print("Program complete - a graph should be visible.")
```

To show my data appropriately I would consider using any of the following that are possible **(influenced by the observation that the x-axis labels themselves are never cut)**:

1. Make the margin transparent so the point isn't cut

   - unless the point is cut by the plot area and not the margin
2. Bring the panel with the plot area to the front

   - unless the point is cut by the plot area and not the margin so order is independent
3. Use `xlim = c((-0.05)*3, (3*0.05))` to extend the axis range but implement some hack to not show the overhanging axis bar after the maximum point of 3?

   - this is how I had it originally but I was told to remove the overhang after the 3 as it was unacceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean by option 1:

```
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x=s, y=n)) +
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=NULL), size = 3) +
  geom_line(position=position_dodge(width=NULL)) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,3), ylim=c(0,5))

# Turn of clipping, so that point at (3,5) is not clipped by the panel grob
gg1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(gg))
gg1$layout$clip[gg1$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gg1)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I was originally hoping to avoid using grob manipulations because I thought I was committed to using `ggsave`.  Turns out that wasn't the case.  Thanks for the clean solution!